# Read a file selected by user in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-get-contents, readfile

I have looked around for a while and still haven't found a satisfactory simple answer to this (thought as popular) problem. The solutions are either directed to sending the file directly to the back-end or way too complex.

I have this:

```
$("#"+id+" input").change(function() {
    file = $(this).prop('files')[0]
    var reader = new FileReader();
    readed = reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
    console.log(readed)
});
```

This gives me however `undefined`. Is there a simply way to just read a file chosen by the user and read the contents?

Comment: Can you post the HTML also? A jsfiddle would be awesome!

Comment: If what you are trying to do is open a local file from the user's computer just using JavaScript, then you cannot really do it unless the user's browser has security disabled (something that probably won't happen)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro — That isn't true. The FileReader API makes it possible.

Comment: You need to bind the onload event for the reader, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/dcxegcco/

Comment: @Quentin, Interesting, I didn't know about that Web API. I'll have to read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsBinaryString) is an asynchronous function. It does not return the data.

You need to create an event handler that fires when the data has been read and then read it from the FileReader object.

```
var file = $(this).prop('files')[0]
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {
  console.log(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I found the solution just a bit before you answer :)